# Upgrade dompdf to newer version

Tags: dompdf

I have an old version of dompdf, and need to upgrade to support my headers properly.  How would I go about doing this?  I tried just copying the new files in my directory, but no go...

Answer (score 1):

From/to which versions? dompdf 0.5.x and 0.6.x are drop-in compatible, though you may need to reset your font directory, namely by removing the dompdf_font_family_cache file. The file may or may not have a .php extension depending on which version you're starting from. *Do not* delete the file that includes .dist in its name.

You will, of course, need to reload any fonts.

0.7.0 requires a bit more work on the implementation side. Easiest path is to completely replace the dompdf directory. Usage is mostly the same, though some method names have changed and you'll need to reference the dompdf namespace.

There's a work-in-progress [migration guide](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Migration-Guide) that may help and the [usage documentation](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage) might also be useful.